# Range for continuos distribution in Julia

Tags: julia, probability, distribution, julia-jump

I am trying to calculate the density function of a continuos random variable in range in Julia using Distributions, but I am not able to define the range. I used Truncator constructor to construct the distribution, but I have no idea how to define the range. By density function I mean P(a

Would appreciate any help. The distribution I'm using is Gamma btw!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To get the maximum and minimum of the support of distribution `d` just write `maximum(d)` and `minimum(d)` respectively. Note that for some distributions this might be infinity, e.g. `maximum(Normal())` is `Inf`.

Comment: My questing is about continuos random variables not discrete and this works fine for discrete, but of course it wont work for continuos that's why I'm using truncation

Comment: This works both for continuous and discrete random variables. But I see that you have changed your question now - you have the answer to it in the comment by 张实唯 below.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Julia and Distributions du you use? In Distribution v0.16.4, it can be easily defined with the second and third arguments of `Truncated`.

```
julia> a = Gamma()
Gamma{Float64}(α=1.0, θ=1.0)

julia> b = Truncated(a, 2, 3)
Truncated(Gamma{Float64}(α=1.0, θ=1.0), range=(2.0, 3.0))

julia> p = rand(b, 1000);

julia> extrema(p)
(2.0007680527633305, 2.99864177354943)
```

You can see the document of `Truncated` by typing `?Truncated` in REPL and enter.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I don't think my question was understood properly (I edited it btw). What I am trying to calculate is the probability of x being between two values. So for example in your example, I want something like P(2<x<3). I think what you did is just defining x in that range but that's not the probability. I'm using Julia 0.6.2

Comment: Then, why not simply `cdf(x, 3) - cdf(x, 2)`.

Comment: Exactly. With one small note that `cdf` evaluates `P(X<= a)` not `P(X<a)` (which in case of continuous distributions is the same, but not in general).

Comment: I have no idea why this didn't cross my mind! But yeah you're right, it works well now